# Linux based docker images on Windows Server 2016 TP5

Tags: docker, windows-server-2016

Can anyone tell me whether or not it is possible to host Linux-based docker containers on Windows Server 2016 TP5?

I realize that it would have to be through virtualization, but is it possible using the 'standard' Microsoft installation ([MSDN Docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick_start/quick_start_windows_server)) to host linux images? I know it supports Hyper-V isolation, but is that solely for isolation and not for cross platform compatibility?

Given only a single server, what is the best way to be able to host both Windows-based and Linux-based docker containers?

Do I need to install docker twice?
Should I run a Ubuntu server in a VM through Hyper-V?
Should I use the Docker Toolbox (Docker for Windows doesn't support Server 2016 yet)

This is all just for toying around at home, not an actual production environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that there is no way of virtualizing Linux Docker containers on Windows other than installing the Docker Toolbox or running it in a VM.

Personally, I installed Hyper-V and an Ubuntu Server VM in that.

Hyper-V containers in Docker for Windows are only for isolation, not cross platform functionality.